# BroadCam Video stream not playing in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, video-streaming, flash

I have Broadcam video streaming server installed in my local server. I have uploaded a test video in the server. When i try to view the stream in a local PC, It plays well in chrome, blurred in Firefox, noting except a close button in the place of video player in IE8. My flash player is good and supports all browsers. I installed Flash player for my IE8, and re-installed java still no clue. What could be the issue ?

`I am using XP SP3. and Broadcam Video streaming server V2.25`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out this,

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/internet-explorer/slow-five-tips-to-boost-performance

There is a option for resetting your internet explorer. Follow that and reset. The video plays now. But still it plays low quality and blurred like in firefox. :(